# Unity stuck on "Installing APK" when "OVR build APK and run" is run

Tags: unity, android, oculus

I was trying to make a game for the Oculus Quest 1 with Unity and Oculus plugin.

Until yesterday, everything was working fine but now, when I click on "OVR build APK and run" (as I always did), after the build is finished, Unity is stuck on "Installing APK".

I tried:

- restarting Unity, the Oculus and the Computer;
- run everything as administrator;
- soft-resetting the oculus;
- using "Build and Run" instead of "OVR build APK and run"
- using only "Build" and installing the app with Sidequest (but got stuck on "Checking APK against blacklist");
- using two other computer (Windows 10);
- using `adb install -r app.apk` (but got stuck on `Performing streamed install...`")
- removing the app from the oculus before reinstalling.
- trying to compile an older version of the project.
- using another Oculus (Quest 2)

The logcat wasn't helpful.

Unity version: 2020.3.12f1 personal

Sidequest version: 0.10.21

Oculus XR plugin version: 1.9.1

OpenXR plugin version: 1.2.3

The oculus was last updated a few days ago, but it was working even after the update.

EDIT: tried with another computer (Windows 10, every software/plugin version matches mine) and unity gives another error: `OVRADBTool Error type 3 Error: Activity class {com.Scuola.VR_Scuola/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} does not exist.`. Nothing changes with Sidequest.

Tried also wit a macbook, every software/plugin version matches mine but it works perfectly with both Unity and Sidequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by reinstalling all the XR related plugin and creating a new project.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only answer that worked for me:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1248123/build-run-apk-freezes-on-pushing-content-only-one.html

In short, Player settings -> Publishing settings -> Split application binary